# Xepersian does not work on Windows, missing xepersian.sty

Tags: packages, texlive, windows, xepersian

I've installed the full version of TexLive 2011 on my friend's Windows. When I try to compile Persian tex files with xelatex engine I get this error: `missing xepersian.sty`.

I tried both TexMaker editor and TexStudio. Also running the `xelatex myfilename.tex` command in command prompt, returns the same error.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! TexLive 2011 is a little bit aged, I would say ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks buddy ;-) 
It's a little strange! I used `xepersian` package with TexLive2011 in linux without any problem for years, But looks like windows is a little unkind :)

Comment: Is there a particular reason for using the old version of TexLive?

Comment: @NEO Thanks for your edits! The only reason for using the old version is my friend says new versions are incompatible with her persian TEX files. I disagree with her of course. But girls insist a lot ;)